# Yii2 data-* attributes not rendered using GridView Column

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-grid

How do add `data-id` in below function:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => "text-center"],
            'attribute' => 'scale',
            "format"=>"Html",
            "value"=>function($model){
                return '<div class="myClass" data-id="'.$model->id.'">'.$model->scale.'</div>';
            }
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Here is `data-id` attribute which is not shown in the browser:

```
"value"=>function($model){
    return '<div class="myClass" data-id="'.$model->id.'">'.$model->scale.'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `format` for the column to `raw` for the column

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'contentOptions' => ['class' => "text-center"],
            'attribute' => 'scale',
            "format"=>"raw",
            "value"=>function($model){
                return '<div class="myClass" data-id="'.$model->id.'">'.$model->scale.'</div>';
            }
        ],
    ],
]);
```

#### EDIT

Apart from returning the `html` like,

```
return '<div class="myClass" data-id="'.$model->id.'">'.$model->scale.'</div>';
```

You can use the `yii\helpers\Html::tag($name,$content,$options[])` to create a div tag see below.

```
return Html::tag('div',$model->scale,['class'=>'myClass','data'=>['id'=>$model->id]]);
```